# DOMException: The element has no supported sources, getting this exception on server while it runs perfectly on localhost

Tags: reactjs, exception, promise, html5-audio

This is the audio tag

```
<audio src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + currentSong.url}></audio>
```

Data set Used

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "1",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown1.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "2",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown2.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "3",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown3.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "4",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown4.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "5",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    url: "/music/Test podcast_mixdown5.mp3",
    date: "26 February, 2023",
    pic: "6",
    time: "00:56:41",
    title: "Lorem Ipsum",
    card_description:
    " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    size: "38.69 MB",
  },
];
```

The application is running perfectly well on localhost, but on server it's throwing the exception

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.

I have checked the audio path, crossorigin but nothing seems to be the issue.

Comment: Open the developer tools on your browser, and see the network tab. Do the `.mp3` files load ? Check the actual rendered DOM and see if the path is correct and try to use the link directly to see if the file is served correctly.

Comment: Actually, the in the actual filename one of the alphabets was in Caps, but in my data object it was small, but localhost was ignoring it and was playing the audio, post modifying that the issue was resolved. Thanks